# using regex I want to move everything in file name between () to middle and drop the ()

Tags: regex, bulk-rename-utility

I have thousands of MP3 and MP4 that I would like to standardize.

I am using Bulk Rename Utility

Example below

the desired lay out is         Artist - Title

some of them are laid out as   Artist - Title (Ft Artist)

I would like to move everything in the () to just after artist and drop the ()

Current

- Lloyd - Get It Shawty (Ft Young Joc).mp3

Desired

- Lloyd Ft Young Joc - Get It Shawty.mp3

Comment: It looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: It seems the biggest issue it to only match the desired ones, and not change files by accident. Consider making a backup before you start [changing them all](https://regex101.com/r/TSzW8l/1/).

Comment: I figured out how to make it work, I do them in batches of 100, here are the strings im using in Bulk Rename Utility with the field names.
RegEx(1)
Match:(.+ )(- .+)\((Ft.+?)\)(.+)?
Replace: \1 \3 \2 \4

Repl.(3)
Replace: \4
With:

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex:

```
([^-]*)\s-\s([^'(]*)\s\(([^\)]*)\)(.*)
```

and this substitution pattern:

```
$1 $3 - $2$4
```

you can test and see a preview in:

https://regex101.com/r/E7gDCE/1